# Javascript won't work in PHP.

Tags: javascript, php

My script:

```
<?php
include 'theme.php';
/*ceklogin();*/
css();
if($_POST['wget-send'])
    {
        $formdir=$_POST['dir'];
        $formlink=$_POST['link'];
    $filelink = fopen('/root/wget/wget-download-link.txt',a);
    $filedir = fopen('/root/wget/wget-dir.txt',w);

    fwrite($filedir, $formdir);
    fwrite($filelink, $formlink."\n");
    /*
    exec('touch /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
    exec('echo "'.$link.'" >> /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
    exec('echo "'.$dir.'" > /root/wget/wget-dir.txt',$out);
        echo $out[2];
        exit();
    */
    }
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\" id=\"WgetForm\">";
echo "Download directory:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"dir\" size=\"15\" value=\"/mnt/usb/\"/><br>";
echo '<br><br>Download link:';
echo "<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"link\" size=\"62\" value=\"\"/><br><br>";
echo '<input type="submit" onclick="LinkAdded()" name="wget-send" value="Send" id="WgetID"/>';
echo "</form></div>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

'function LinkAdded()'
    '{
            document.getElementById("WgetID").innerHTML = "Link added to wget";
    }'
'</script>'

foot();
echo '
</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

I still don't quite understand how to write javascript inside PHP, it gives me an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''{' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /www/wget.php on line 33
```

but if I put the javascript out side of `<? ....?>` the page runs well but the javascript won't work. Help please.

Comment: If you're mostly outputting HTML, just do `?><html here><?php`.

Comment: Dont forgett echo befor you post "html" code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to parse through your syntax errors. Use a code linter yourself to do that. They are built into even free IDE's these days and you can even paste your code into online syntax checkers

You don't set innerHTML for an `input` you set it's `value`

Change

```
document.getElementById("WgetID").innerHTML = "Link added to wget"
```

To

```
document.getElementById("WgetID").value = "Link added to wget"
```

Comment: Thank you that works but the the submit button becomes `Link added to wget` when I click it. I want the words to be shown below the sumbit button, not on the submit button, how can I do that?

Comment: create a new element instead then and append it to the form

Comment: Can you please give me an example of that element appended to the form? I'm still a beginner in this

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">

     function LinkAdded()
    {
            document.getElementById("WgetID").innerHTML = "Link added to wget";
    }
</script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error. Please try this.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

echo 'function LinkAdded()
{
        document.getElementById("WgetID").innerHTML = "Link added to wget";
}
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.

'function LinkAdded()'.
    '{
            document.getElementById("WgetID").innerHTML = "Link added to wget";
    }'.
'</script>';
```

or

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">

function LinkAdded()
    {
            document.getElementById("WgetID").innerHTML = "Link added to wget";
    }
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Either echo on each line, or remove the quotes to echo as one block:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">

    function LinkAdded()
    {
            document.getElementById("WgetID").innerHTML = "Link added to wget";
    }
</script>';
```